# Terraform - Create Snapshot of EBS and then convert Snapshot to EBS and attach to an EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to create a snapshot of an EBS Volume, take that Snapshot and convert it back into an EBS Volume and attach it to an EC2 via Terraform?

I am currently looking at automating our production and test environment in AWS so they are identical and I found using Terraform quite useful but I can't find any documentation on how achieve this.

Comment: can you be more clear?

Comment: @Nihal My apologies, so let me give you a quick overview of my requirements, I currently have a production environment which consists of an SQL Server, Terminal Server and Application Server, we currently manually clone the Prod environment so I am wondering if its possible to use Terraform to automatically Snapshots of the Prod EBS Volumes, then convert the Snapshots to EBS Volumes and then Attach to an Empty EC2 Shell, please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an EBS volume from a snapshot and attach that to an instance without too much difficulty using the [`aws_ebs_volume`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_volume.html) and the [`aws_volume_attachment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/volume_attachment.html) resources.

You can also create a snapshot using the [`aws_ebs_snapshot`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_snapshot.html) resource or pick up a snapshot ID dynamically using the [`aws_ebs_snapshot`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ebs_snapshot.html) data source.

A quick example might be something like this:

```
data "aws_ebs_volume" "production_volume" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "volume-type"
    values = ["gp2"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["Production"]
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "production_snapshot" {
  volume_id = "${data.aws_ebs_volume.prod_volume.id}"

  tags {
    Name = "Production"
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "from_production_snapshot" {
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  snapshot_id       = "${aws_ebs_snapshot.production_snapshot.id}"
  size              = 40

  tags {
    Name = "Non-Production"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "non_production" {
  ami               = "ami-21f78e11"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  instance_type     = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "Non-Production"
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "non_production" {
  device_name = "/dev/xvdf"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.from_production_snapshot.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.non_production.id}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, just a quick question, how do I reference an existing EBS Volume, is it through the Volume ID? Thanks

Comment: The example given in the answer creates a snapshot from a volume tagged  `Name = "Production"`. Obviously you need to change that so that your volume is properly tagged. Or you could skip the `aws_ebs_volume` data source and instead just hardcode the snapshot id in the `aws_ebs_snapshot` resource below it.

Comment: Hi @Muhammed_Khan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.